# Deleting a pointer of vectors

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, vector

I am trying to write a very simple piece of code to create a 3x2 matrix using STL vectors.
This is what I have:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{

  int i;

  vector<int> * x = new vector<int> [3];

  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
       x[i] = vector<int> (2); 

  delete x;

  return 0;

}
```

The problem is that every time I run the program, it crashes. If I remove the `delete x` then it works fine, but will probably result in memory leaks.

I know that this is probably not the best way to create a matrix and there is a battalion of choices out there, but I would just like to know why the above program crashes every time.

Also, replacing every occurrence of `vector<int>` with say `int`, then all work fine again.

Comment: try using a `vector< vector<int> >;` no more `delete/new`

Comment: You are using x as x[] but not deleting as delete [] x . Why?

Comment: @rhalbersma: That's a valid answer. You should put it in as an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @Component10 Already answered by R. Martinho Fernandes

Comment: you should try boost::scoped_array, or even boost::numeric::ublas::matrix

Comment: Thanks everyone for their prompt answers! Now it is clear to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To destroy dynamically allocated arrays you *must* use `delete[]`, not `delete`.

While that will make the code work, it is a suboptimal solution. The following program does the same thing, but is much more succint, and safer.

```
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> x(3, std::vector<int>(2));
}
```

Comment: what took you so long! :-) after 6 `delete[]` posters, finally the right approach.

Comment: Not to speak of the best approach for his example, `vector<int> x[3];` (and maybe a `std::fill(std::begin(x), std::end(x), std::vector<int>(2));`).

Answer (score 4):

You're using "array" `new`, so you need the same for `delete`:

```
delete[] x;
//....^^
```

Using `delete x;` here is undefined bahaviour, so anything could happen. You're lucky, that your program crashes :)

---

Don't do this, unless you have really good reason for this. You may have

```
std::vector< std::vector< int > > x;
```

Then your code would become:

```
std::vector< std::vector< int > > x( 3 );
for( unsigned int ii = 0; ii < x.size(); ++ii )
{
    x[ ii ].resize( 2 );
}
```

Or even:

```
std::vector< std::vector< int > > x( 3, std::vector< int >( 2 ) );
```

---

I'd do this like this:

```
typedef std::vector< int > SomeLogicalName; // or just IntVector
std::vector< SomeLogicalName > x( 3, SomeLogicalName( 2 ) );
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `delete []`, since you have a dynamically allocated array. The fact that you have vectors has nothing to do with it.

You could greatly simplify your code by using a `vector<vector<int>>`:

```
vector<vector<int>> v(3); // holds three empty vector<int>
```

Or even

```
vector<vector<int>> v(3, std::vector<int>(2)); // holds 3 size 2 vector<int>
```

Answer (score 0):

Every `new` needs a `delete`

Every `new []` needs a `delete []`